# How to do a Facebook Send Request to a specific friend on Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

It seems that the native Request Dialog shows a list where you can choose the friends you want to invite. I'm trying to do something where the user can just press a button to invite a specific person, say a girlfriend, or a family member.

Is this possible using the native Android SDK?

**Update:**
Okay, this was voted to be closed so I'm updating. There wasn't anything said in the Facebook tutorials that you can send a Facebook Request to a specific person, which I was trying to do.

I've tried the following but it displays a friend selector with all of the user's friends:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "Invite message here");

WebDialog requestsDialog = (
    new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(getActivity(), 
        Session.getActiveSession(), 
        params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                // Some onComplete callback here
            }               
        }).build();

requestsDialog.show();
```

And by adding `.setTo(id)` where id is the UID of the user to invite before `.build()`, the dialog is modified to send to just the indicated user. The code looks like:

```
WebDialog requestsDialog = (
    new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(getActivity(), 
        Session.getActiveSession(), 
        params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                // Some onComplete callback here
            }               
        }).setTo("SOME_FACEBOOK_ID_HERE").build();

requestsDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I just read the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder) of the Request Dialog again. And it can be configured to send to a specific person by doing `.setTo(String id)`.

Thanks for the reply though. :)